# Good book on image processing and analysis on Mathematica 12

Tags: graphics, image-processing, reference-request

Can someone recommend a good book on image processing/analysis and graphics on Mathematica 12?

Comment: I'm not sure that you'll find one specifically targeting version 12, which only released a few months ago. Perhaps you might have better luck looking for a version 11 book - there weren't tons of changes in image processing between the two versions afaik.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see what I can dig up!

Comment: I found these. Basic image processing for Mathematica (updated for version 10) https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=8299

Comment: And some YouTube tutorials for version 11 https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MbNht55nVPs

Answer (score 4):

Thanks I found this! Free ebook. Basic Image Processing In Mathematica for version 10 https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=8299

There is also a YouTube tutorial series on version 11
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MbNht55nVPs[image: Basic Image Processing In Mathematica (updated for version 10]!